# how to use metafor to calculate effect sizes for pre-post one group study

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor

I was trying to use metafor to perform a meta-analysis to explore hormone concentration changes after the intervention.

The studies being included only have one intervention group without any control group. The pre and post mean_sd values were reported in each individual study.

However, based on the metafor package, it requires putting ri values as well, which no studies have reported the correlation coefficients before. How am I supposed to sort this out?

I was told to try a wide range of ri values and then perform sensitivity analyses to see if ri values would influence the results. Does anyone have an idea of how to perform this analysis?

I've also attached my code here (set ri equals 0 across studies):

```
es <- escalc(measure = "SMCC", ni= n, ri = c(rep(0, 14)),
m1i = pyy_pre_m, m2i = pyy_post_m,
sd1i = pyy_pre_sd, sd2i = pyy_post_sd, 
data = df,append = FALSE)

es
```

Many thanks,
Kim

Comment: Please tag with the language you are using, I am unclear about whether this requires statistical expertise or is a programming problem.

Comment: You need to set r to a range of plausible values and see how much that affects the result.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you have the R code for doing the sensitivity analysis to see whether different ri values would influence the result?

Comment: If you want me to see your comment you need to ping me like @ZhuoxiuJin pings you. Just set the ri = parameter. Put it in a loop and extract the values you want to compare or just to it one by one and inspect the results individually. Note by the way that requests for code are off-topic here.

Comment: @mdewey  Understood! Many thanks !